# How to find and replace string with anchor tag if keyword does not already in anchor tag

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to find and replace string with   tage if keyword **does not in already in   tag.**

For example, suppose here keyword is Lorem Ipsum than

**From**

**Lorem Ipsum** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
**`<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum </a>`** has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

**To,**

**`<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum </a>`** is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
**`<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum </a>`** has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460311/automatic-convert-word-to-link-in-php